# Film where a boy from the present goes back in time to the Victorian era and sees a library on fire

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I can't remember the name, only a few details.

I believe it was a Christmas film (I could be wrong) where a boy went to visit his grandparents in a big house, in like the English countryside. One night -- I'm unsure if this was a dream -- but he ends up back in time in the Victorian era. There he meets an older boy, and a boy he then finds out is his granddad.

This is where it gets weird. All I remember is the older boy gets his leg trapped in a rabbit or bear trap, and I think he then dies.

Another thing I remember is the library in the house being on fire and a girl.

I watched this film about 9 or 10 years ago, but I'd say it's from the early 2000s, or possibly the 2010s. It was a modern film set present day; the main character wore clothing which reflected that.

I know it's not a lot, but I remember it so vividly and it has been bugging me for YEARS.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this film, and when do you think it was made?

Comment: I watched it when I was about 8 or 9 I'd say so about 9 or 10 years ago but i'd say its from the early 2000's possibly.

Comment: Hmm, the plot you've described sounds a bit like [_The Amazing Mr. Blunden_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Mr._Blunden), but that's from the '70s.

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: it’s not that one, it was a modern film and the characters clothing was modern too

Comment: I think I remember the same film! But I cant remember! Does he like fall through a brick wall to get back in time? And when he gets there, he gets attacked for dressing weird?

Answer (score 7):

This has to be [*The Amazing Mr. Blunden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Mr._Blunden), which was released in December 1972. Despite the grim events in the film, it is indeed a time-traveling Christmas story. The children are sent to a country house, where their mother will be the caretaker. The children encounter ghosts of two children who lived in the house a hundred years ago, and there was indeed a fire, deliberately set in the library in the past. I don't recall a trap, though. Check out the link for more details.

Comment: it’s wasn’t this one, it was a modern film. the main character wore clothing that reflected that too

Comment: Hmm. I suppose it couldn't be the [2021 remake](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt14843694/) either...

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [The Time Game](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0310233/) (1992)?

Boy stays with grandparents after a fire at his school. Time travels to the victorian era.

Comment: it isn’t this film, i’d say it’s from early 2000s possibly 2010s

Answer (score 5):

This sounds very much like “[The Ghost of Greville Lodge](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0282524/)” from 2000.

Its about a boy who goes to stay with his uncle at a country mansion, subsequently meeting a mysterious boy and girl in the grounds who he makes friends with, and discovers the west wing is sealed off and no one will talk about it.

The boy ends up going back in time, discovering that there was a fire in the west wing which caused a family tragedy, and indeed experiencing that fire in one time slip.  There is a link between the boy, girl and the modern characters.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a long-shot, but could this be [Oskar & Josefine](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0403390/) (2005)?

The titular coprotagonists go back in time while staying with the boy's grandparents, not to Victorian times but something approaching medieval Norway.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be ***[From Time to Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Time_to_Time_(film))*** (2009)...?

> *From Time to Time* is a 2009 British fantasy drama film directed by Julian Fellowes starring Maggie Smith, Timothy Spall, Carice van Houten, Alex Etel, Eliza Bennett, Elisabeth Dermot-Walsh, Dominic West, Hugh Bonneville, and Pauline Collins. It was adapted from Lucy M. Boston's children's novel The Chimneys of Green Knowe (1958). The film was shot in Athelhampton Hall, Dorset.

> **Set in England,** this ghostly, haunting story spans two worlds, over a century apart. Near the end of World War II, **teen-aged Tolly (Alex Etel) goes to spend Christmas at his grandmother's large country estate, Green Knowe.** Tolly's soldier father has been reported missing in action while his mother remains in London awaiting more information. His grandmother, Mrs. Oldknow (Maggie Smith), disapproved of her son's marriage, considering his wife a commoner. Mrs. Oldknow is financially strapped and faced with selling Green Knowe.
>
> On Tolly's first night at Green Knowe, he sees and hears a ghostly young girl and adolescent boy. Soon after, he discovers that **he magically time travels between the present and the early 19th century in the old manor house**. Certain people in that time period can see and communicate with him, while he remains invisible to others. Susan, the blind daughter of Lord Thomas Oldknow, is the ghostly figure that Tolly first saw. She can speak to Tolly both in her time and his. He learns that his grandmother also sees the ancestral ghosts. Susan leads him on an adventure that unlocks family secrets laid buried for generations. **Exciting events include a terrible fire,** a tale of stolen jewels, and threats of a servant being sold into a press gang.
>
> Although the lost treasure is found and Green Knowe is saved, Tolly's father is a casualty of the war. Mrs. Oldknow finally welcomes Tolly's mother into the family. Tolly is comforted when his father's ghost appears, assuring him everything will be all right.

Comment: Thank you, but it wasn’t this film. It was a modern film set present day i believe only when it went back in time the clothing obviously reflected that

Comment: Are you sure? You ask about a modern film set in the present day, with time travel. The above suggestion seems to be exactly that.  It sounds like a likely candidate.

Comment: @Pete "Near the end of World War II" is hardly the present day

Comment: And also it includes  "a terrible fire"  which matches your description.

Comment: GordonD, point taken, but that's a fairly minor difference, and the OP says he doesn't remember it well.  He could be mistaken on the point.

Answer (score 0):

The Seeker: The Dark Is Rising

Enjoy . It was hard to find it :D

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should [edit] your answer to include enough details, like the older boy getting caught in a trap and a burning library, so the OP can recognise this as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

This never got answered properly as I was looking for the same film! There were ice skates hidden in a wardrobe! By the girl in the victorian time if that helps anyone, and the boy only went back in time when he stepped out the front door of the big house.

It was *[Tom's Midnight Garden](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0146315/)*

> A young boy journeys across the boundaries of reality to a secret, haunted place, half-a-century back in time, in this tale of enchantment, shadows and lost memories.

### Trailer

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! If you think the answer is *Tom's Midnight Garden*, can you edit this to explain more clearly how it fits?

Comment: https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0146315/ for reference

Comment: Admittedly, no reference to a library for that I've found.

Comment: This doesn't seem an especially good match