# Family curse - Halloween fire movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I’m trying to find a movie that used to play in the UK EVERY YEAR on tv around Halloween. I think late 2000s- early 2010s, because it had phased out from being shown by the time I was a teen. My knowledge on it is really limited because I haven’t seen it in so long, but here’s what I remember.

1. A fire in a library- though I’m not 100% sure, I believe it was about a family curse of some kind where a fire started on Halloween many years ago. I distinctly remember a clock striking and a library going up in flames, with the movie themed around that about to happen again in the present. I think it was linked to the family who lived there and originally caused a tragedy of some kind.
2. A large white marble (?) fireplace with indentations/ slots in it for things to be placed. I believe the mc/ mcs had to find a heart or a coat of arms or something like that in order to slot it into the fireplace and make it turn around or move.
3. The movie was set in what I think was a large stately home with a fountain in the garden, and I believe the main character was either a teenager or a young adult. As far as I know the premise was something about saving the house from the repeat of a fire that hurt someone a long time ago.

I know it was shown on TV multiple times as I remember watching it/ clips of it with my family definitely around Halloween.

Comment: And you're certain it didn't involve going back in time as per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253631/film-where-a-boy-from-the-present-goes-back-in-time-to-the-victorian-era-and-see?rq=1?

Comment: I don’t believe there was any time travelling, nor was it Christmas in the one I watched. I’m definitely sure it was focused on Halloween because it was the only scary movie I was allowed to watch! Also don’t remember a boy meeting his grandfather or a trap of any sort.

Comment: :-D Just figured since it comes up on the site for a library fire, it was worth a try.